# GWT, LAMP or a Framework? choosing the right technology for a web application

Tags: django, gwt

after scanning stackoverflow I stil could not find a good answer to a simple question:

you want to develop a SaaS business app that has all the typical features: reports, forms, user administration etc. You don't want a CMS but develop it from scratch. what technologies would you choose?

at first glance, many of you would say it does not matter what tech to choose - after all the end result is only a question of engineering and many tools can do the job.

but the problem is more complex -

- a Django/RoR/ZF/Symfony choice is great for dynamic websites, but is it really the best choice for a desktop-like app?

  - do all tools deliver **manageable** code on the long run, or do some tend to become spaghetti after 12 motnhs of coding..?

most tech reviews both on stackoverflow and the Web tend to focus on consumer web apps and content websites, for which many platforms apply.

what would YOU use for a SaaS business application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been developing in GWT for several months now and it is fantastic.  I have an app with 10 full-page screens in a single module and it's not showing signs of slowing down even on slow computers with IE6.

GWT is easy to understand, quick to write, protects me from some of the more dangerous aspects of JS programming, and supports unit tests.  The google eclipse plugin brings all of the autocomplete features you expect.  The documentation is excellent and the community is helpful.

Comment: My company uses GWT and it's very nice, especially if you're already using Java on the server side. One downside that doesn't affect us is the general problem with ajax sites: Search engines can't spider them properly. Since GWT is all dynamically created, it's problematic